# Get Data from DB in Layout page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to load data in navbar after fetching data from DB in Layout.cshtml page in ASP.NET MVC. But I am facing a Problem that how to fetch data in layout page as there is no Controller unlike Code Behind file in Web Forms.
Anyone please help me that:
 - How to store data in Data Model
 - How to pass it to Layout page
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use PartialView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a child action:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult NavBar()
    {
        var navbar = // query your database;
        return PartialView("_NavBar", navbar);
    }
}
```

Then create the partial view `Views\Shared\_NavBar.cshtml` and put the HTML for it there. Your model will be what you queried from the database in the child action.

Finally in your layout:

```
@Html.Action("NavBar", "Foo")
```

Comment: can I write this method in any Controller in which i want ?
it can be HomeController or SomeController ?? or in some Specific Controller ?

Comment: Yep. Where you put it doesn't matter. Just reference the controller it's in when calling `Html.Action`.

Comment: done all these. but when I run the application this error will show : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Test.Models.Dummy', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Test.Models.Dummy]'. By Using : @model Test.Models.Dummy

Comment: and when i bind model like: @model Test.Models.Dummy then error will be :  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Test.Models.Dummy' because 'Test.Models.Dummy' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: The error messages are straight forward. If you're expecting to use foreach, then you want the model to be an enumerable. That means you should leave the model declaration line as it was originally. Then, that just means that you're passing just a single instance to the view instead of a collection. Fix that in your action.